# Which kind of Korean sentence do you have a listening problem in?

Tags: discussion

I believe that almost all Koreans have some level of confidence about grammar when reading English articles

But while listening, there is usually not enough time for interpretation. Perhaps the listening skill is a good indicator of his or her English level.

Consider the following sentence which is from the movie Rapunzel :

> once upon a time, a single drop of sunlight fell from the heavens.

I can not understand this listen well while listening, as there are a lot of words that are subjective. So when I **do not catch the subjective part**, I
usually loose track of the whole sentence.

Also, I did not catch the following sentence : It contains **a lof of adjectives**

> Well, centuries
>   passed and a hop-skip-and-a-boat ride away, there grew a kingdom.

I believe that foreigners' major difficulty in Korean is listening as well.

> What kind of Korean sentences do you have a problem understanding while listening?

Add : When I listen to Korean TV programs, I try to analyze Korean
sentences as I analyze English sentences while listening to English
dialogue. Surprisingly, I can not. It is very difficult.

Comment: I suppose some 받치+consonant irregular pronunciations would be some examples, like 관련, 박람회, 꽃잎

Comment: @user17915 : Thanks for your careful correcting. And I can not pronounciate 관련 as 관련. In further, 관년, 괄연, or 괄련 which I can pronounciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Anything that has a word in that I don't know and can't guess.

If I can guess a word I don't know, that's fine. But if I can't, the fact I missed a single word will bother me until the start of the next sentence or section.

- Anything that's too fast

For similar reasons, if something is so fast that I can't catch each word, I will be lost until the next sentence or section.